# what does installd do in privacy setting?

Tags: macos, security, accessibility

there is a installd icon in the setting->accessibility->privacy. it can be seen in the screenshot [image]

Any ideas what it is for?

Comment: I've looked over several Macs and none have installd listed as requesting permission to script the user interface. The daemon itself is part of Apple's private framework, but it shouldn't need this sort of access to install software as far as I'm concerned...

Answer (score 2):

I've had this question as well and finally went digging.  This information is stored in the OS X Privacy database.  This db can be accessed with the command-line tool `tccutil`, but the only ("supported") option is **reset**.  That is of course not very useful here. I found someone [at this page](http://jacobsalmela.com/tccutil-py-command-line-utility-modifying-accessibility-database-os-x/) who wrote a short python utility to edit this database.  Examining the code, the db is located at `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` (you will need sudo access for this).  It is a SQLite db.  There are entries in there for `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Resources/installd` which is almost certainly the installd referenced in the preference pane.  This is the daemon which occasionally checks for software updates. Since it is Apple code, I am inclined to trust it.